# How to add values to single empty column from local text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, view, sql-insert

I have table called customers with CustomerID,CompanyName,Address,Phone

Now we inserted a new column called Remarks which is empty or null

I have text file to  bulk insert into the column using the view Remarkinsert with the following code

```
bulk insert  HRRegion.dbo.Remarksinsert
 From 'C:\Users\SMSTECHLNG50\Documents\remarks..txt'
 with 
 (
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

But its getting the error

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 9 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'CustomerID', table 'HRRegion.dbo.Customers'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: check whether the column 'CustomerID' is declared as primary key or as not null column...

Comment: Seems like you try to `INSERT` new rows into the table, instead of `UPDATE` already existing rows.

Comment: CustomerID is the primary key ,  but i want to only add the remarks column in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that also here, you can only insert a whole row or nothing.

If your customer table looks like this:

```
customer
custid|co_name        |addr                     |phone            |remarks
    42|Laverda        |Breganze, Italy          |+39 6 233 84 81  |(NULL)
    43|Benelli        |Pesaro, Italy            |+39 8 284 55 32  |(NULL)
    44|Ural           |Irbit, Russia            |+7 14 526 22 2342|(NULL)
    45|Dnepr          |Kiew, Ukraine            |+380 526 22 2342 |(NULL)
    46|Harley Davidson|Milwaukee, US            |+1 802 223 4444  |(NULL)
    47|Honda          |Tokyo, Japan             |+81 82 555 4123  |(NULL)
    48|Moto Guzzi     |Mandello del Lario, Italy|+39 6 423 04 72  |(NULL)
    49|Ducati         |Bologna, Italy           |+39 7 722 04 43  |(NULL)
    50|Norton         |Birmingham, UK           |+44 7234 723 4423|(NULL)
    51|Matchless      |Plumstead, London, UK    |+44 8021 612 0843|(NULL)
    52|Brough         |Nottingham, UK           |+44 5812 512 4883|(NULL)
```

(well, you add the `remarks` column using an `ALTER TABLE` ...), then, I would expect the file you mentioned with the remarks to look somewhat like this:

```
remarks
custid|remarks
    42|built also tractors, closed now
    43|first series 6-cylinder motorbike
    44|old style sidecar rigs with modern engine
    45|old style sidecar rigs, permanent two-wheel drive
    46|the american classic
    47|builders of the CB 750 four and the gold wing
    48|famous for horizontal singles and 90° V twins
    49|90° V twin bikes with lateral crankshaft
    50|english classic, still alive
    51|english classic, closed now
    52|probably the finest motorcycles ever built
```

So, you would build a `remarks_stg` table:

```
CREATE TABLE remarks_stg (
  custid  SMALLINT    NOT NULL
, remarks VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Then, you load just that staging table with the data file as described above - and, at least if have SQL Server 2008 and above, you use a `MERGE` statement to update the `customer` table:

```
MERGE customer t
USING stg_customer s
  ON t.custid = s. custid
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  remarks = s.remarks
;
```

Comment: thank you .. i have imported from text file and now  i need to copy the primary key values to one more column in the remarks_stg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546635/how-to-copy-all-primary-key-data-to-foriegn-key-from-table

Comment: You will have to add the primary keys to the text file. SQL tables are not ordered,and the remarks would not know where to go...

Comment: CustomerID is the prmary key in customers table and now i need to import them to remarks_stg

Comment: Look at the example in my answer. You will see that it is impossible to find out which primary key of the target table would have to go to which row in the staging table. You can't import primary keys into the staging table, period. If you are lucky, the primary key of the target table is sorted and continuous like in my example. Then, you could use a perl script or an awk script, or even excel, to add a sequence of 42 to 52 to the left of each row of the remarks load file. If not, you would have to do that manually. There is no other way.

Comment: why its only updating one customerID for all the  rows in destination.. i mean can i copy the first 49 rows from source column and paste it to destination column